# Язык C. Какой функцией считывать произвольное число символов из stdin, среди которых могут быть символы перевода строки?

Tags: c

Язык C. Какой функцией считывать произвольное число символов до конца stdin, среди которых могут быть символы начала новой строки? Я использую fgets, но она считывает только до первого символа начала новой строки \n, а мне надо чтобы считывание продолжалось до самого конца файла

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используй [fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/):

```
char buf[BUF_SZ];
size_t nread;
nread = fread (buf, 1, BUF_SZ-1, stdin);
buf[nread] = 0; //< Для текстовых данных необходимо добавить завершающий ноль
```